# Map return returning last iteration of recursion?

Tags: javascript

I am using recursion to step through this array of object's children. However it is returning the top level parents. The array of objects is:

```
const orgs = {
   children:[{name:'Core Enginerinng Ops', orgId:741,
             children:[{name:'Child Engineering Ops', orgId:5656, 
                children:[{name: 'Child Engineering Last LEVEL AHAHHH', orgid:6969}]},{name: 'Child 2 Engineering OPS', orgId: 852}]},{name: 'Data Services Engineering', orgId: 456,
             children:[{name:'Child Data Services', orgId:978},{name: 'Child 2 Data Services', orgId: 354}]}]
    }
```

My end goal is to save the objects into a new array with just the name and the orgId as object for each parent and child.

```
flattenOrgs = (organizations) => {
  const flatArray =organizations.map(org => {
    if (org.children && org.children.length > 0) {
      this.flattenOrgs(org.children)
    }
    console.log(org.name)
    return org.name
  })
  return flatArray
}
```

However when I pass it through this function that uses recursion it only returns the 'org.name': `["Core Enginerinng Ops", "Data Services Engineering"]`. I'm not great with recursion, but it doesn't make sense to me that the `console.log(org.name)` prints out each individual name as expected... But it doesn't return that name?

EDIT
`console.log(org.name)` before return

> Child Engineering Last LEVEL AHAHHH
>
> Child Engineering Ops
>
> Child 2 Engineering OPS
>
> Core Enginerinng Ops
>
> Child Data Services
>
> Child 2 Data Services
>
> Data Services Engineering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reduce the array instead of mapping, because you need the children elements as well.

```js
const
    orgs = { children: [{ name: 'Core Enginerinng Ops', orgId: 741, children: [{ name: 'Child Engineering Ops', orgId: 5656, children: [{ name: 'Child Engineering Last LEVEL AHAHHH', orgid: 6969 }] }, { name: 'Child 2 Engineering OPS', orgId: 852 }] }, { name: 'Data Services Engineering', orgId: 456, children: [{ name: 'Child Data Services', orgId: 978 }, { name: 'Child 2 Data Services', orgId: 354 }] }] },
    flattenOrgs = (organizations) =>
        organizations.reduce((r, { name, orgId, children }) => 
            r.concat({ name, orgId }, flattenOrgs(children || [])), []);

console.log(flattenOrgs(orgs.children));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Nina....I feel like you just showed me THE cheat code with .reduce. I've never heard of it before...Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will meet your expectation:

```js
const orgs = {
  children: [{
    name: 'Core Enginerinng Ops',
    orgId: 741,
    children: [{
      name: 'Child Engineering Ops',
      orgId: 5656,
      children: [{
        name: 'Child Engineering Last LEVEL AHAHHH',
        orgid: 6969
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Child 2 Engineering OPS',
      orgId: 852
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Data Services Engineering',
    orgId: 456,
    children: [{
      name: 'Child Data Services',
      orgId: 978
    }, {
      name: 'Child 2 Data Services',
      orgId: 354
    }]
  }]
}

console.log(orgs.children.map(child => {
  let newchild = {
    name: child.name,
    orgId: child.orgId
  }
  child.children && child.children.map(innerchild => {
    newchild.children = {
      name: innerchild.name,
      orgId: innerchild.orgId
    }
    innerchild.children && innerchild.children.map(innermostChild => {
      newchild.children.children = {
        name: innermostChild.name,
        orgId: innermostChild.orgId
      }
    })
  })
return newchild
}))
```